# Rails 5 Invalid Authenticity Token when trying to login from transparently redirected subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain, csrf

I have a Rails 5 app running on port 12003 and I configured a subdomain to transparently redirect to that port as follows:

https://test.example.com => https://example.com:12007

The problem is that when I try to log in or execute an action that requires an Authenticity Token from the subdomain, the application throws this error:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in AccessController#attempt_login

The application does not throw it when I try to perform an action from the url that includes the port: http://example.com:12007

This makes me think that the app detects the subdomain as a Forgery attempt.

Is there a way to whitelist the subdomain or fix this isssue without disabling CSRF Protection on my app?

Comment: Do you have forms on test.example.com that post to a rails app running on example.com? Do these apps have separate codebases?

Comment: I do have forms this problem happens when I try to submit the login form to access the system. There is no different codebase, it is actually the same app accesible form both the subdomain and the normal domain with the port

Comment: Do both instances of the application have the same value for `secret_key_base`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've encountered similar problem in combination of **Rails 5**, **Devise** and **Nginx** with **SSL**.

Simply switching off the CSRF protection resulted in **inability to log in/sign in** through devise (the session hasn't changed, log in redirected back to root as if nothing happened).

Using `curl` I tested that  this was **issue only on HTTPS**, but **everything worked well on HTTP**.

The only line that has solved this problem for me in the end of the day was

```
server {
  location @app {
    ...

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    ...
  }
}
```

in Nginx site configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`).

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm! Could you elaborate a little more on what this line does according to your knowledge?

Comment: Honestly, I don't have that much of a clue. I've just tried it all and made detailed analysis what made it work. But... it should forward something... probably headers, probably to HTTPS, so the thing is not HTTP and everything is (all significant proxied headers are) HTTPS. But that's really all I know. I encourage everyone who is more familiar technically with HTTP headers to explain it.

Comment: I don't have a folder named `etc` inside my root folder